# Доступ только к своим объектам django admin

Tags: python, django

Пытался реализовать вывод только собственных записей для каждого пользователя. Добавил к модели поле user и переопределил def queryset в админском классе. Но всё равно каждый пользователь видит все объекты. Что я делаю не так?

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=u"пользователь", blank=True, null=True)

   name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Название категории*', max_length=255)
   parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name='Родительская категория', blank=True, null=True, related_name="children_categories")
   image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Картинка', upload_to=upload_category_image, blank=True)
   description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание категории', blank=True)
   order = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Порядок следования*', default=99)
   is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Активная*', default=True, help_text="Если не отмечено, тогда не показывается на сайте")

class Meta:
    db_table = 'catalog_category'
    verbose_name = 'Категория'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
    ordering = ('order',)
```

admin.py

```
class CatalogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   user_fieldsets = (
     (None, {
         'classes': ('wide',),
         'fields': ('name','parent_category','image','description','order','is_active')
      }),
   )

   list_display = ['name', 'user',]
   raw_id_list_displayfields = ('user',)
   search_fields = ['name', 'user__username']

   def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
      if form.is_valid():
         if not request.user.is_superuser or not form.cleaned_data["user"]:
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
         elif form.cleaned_data["user"]:
            obj.user = form.cleaned_data["user"]
            obj.save()

   def preprocess_list_display(self, request):
      if 'user' not in self.list_display:
         self.list_display.insert(self.list_display.__len__(), 'user')
      if not request.user.is_superuser:
         if 'user' in self.list_display:
            self.list_display.remove('user')

   def preprocess_search_fields(self, request):
      if 'user__username' not in self.search_fields:
         c = (self.search_fields.__len__(), 'user__username')
         self.search_fields.append(c)
      if not request.user.is_superuser:
         if 'user__username' in self.search_fields:
            self.search_fields.remove('user__username')

   def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
      self.preprocess_list_display(request)
      self.preprocess_search_fields(request)
      return super(CatalogAdmin, self).changelist_view(request)

   def queryset(self, request):
      if request.user.is_superuser:
         return super(CatalogAdmin, self).queryset(request)
      else:
         qs = super(CatalogAdminn, self).queryset(request)
         return qs.filter(user=request.user)

   def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
      if request.user.is_superuser:
         return super(CatalogAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
      return self.user_fieldsets
```

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто нужно переопределить не `queryset`, а `get_queryset`.
Пример из моего кода:[image: Пример из моего кода]

UPD. А ещё я заметил, что у вас почему-то методы `preprocess_list_display` и `preprocess_search_fields`, хотя в документации они `get_list_dislpay` и `get_search_fields`. [Пруф](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/ref/contrib/admin/index.html#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display)